# using several headers in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to have several recycle view in one activity [example](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-FqipI2Q9GzQ/VZMXmJ4b3HI/AAAAAAAAAjQ/6rDPhl4TUC4/s1600/ezgif.com-video-to-gif.gif) (for each... event ,comic and character there is a recycle view) how to make that in my code?I was trying the below code

This is the layout on main activity it has one recycler view

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".RecyclerViewActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="Recomanded for you"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

this the code in my adapter , I am setting one adapter

```
  mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getDataSet());
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        RecyclerView.ItemDecoration itemDecoration =
                new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration);
```

I thought such way in my adapter class, several view will help, but it wasent correct

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder TextViewHolder, int position) {

        switch (TextViewHolder.getItemViewType()) {

            case TYPE_IMAGE:
                ImageViewHolder imageViewHolder = (ImageViewHolder) TextViewHolder;
                // imageViewHolder.mImage.setImageResource(...);
                final String namev = mDataset.get(position);
                imageViewHolder.txtHeader.setText(mDataset.get(position));
                imageViewHolder.txtHeader.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        remove(namev);
                    }
                });

                break;

            case TYPE_GROUP:
                TextViewHolder viewHolder = (TextViewHolder) TextViewHolder;
                //  viewHolder.txtHeader.setText(...)
                final String name = mDataset.get(position);
                viewHolder.txtHeader.setText(mDataset.get(position));
                viewHolder.txtHeader.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        remove(name);
                    }
                });

                viewHolder.txtFooter.setText("Footer: " + mDataset.get(position));

                break;
        }
```

this is full code(edit)

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<String> mDataset;

    public class ImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        //ImageView mImage;
        public TextView txtHeader;
        public TextView txtFooter;
        public ImageViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super (itemView);
            txtHeader = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.firstLine1);
            txtFooter = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.secondLine1);
        }
    }

    // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
    // Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
    // you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
    public class TextViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        public TextView textheader;
        public TextView txtFooter;

        public TextViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            textheader = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textc);
         //   txtFooter = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.secondLine);

        }
    }

    public void add(int position, String item) {
        mDataset.add(position, item);
        notifyItemInserted(position);
    }

    public void remove(String item) {
        int position = mDataset.indexOf(item);
        mDataset.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }

    // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
    public MyAdapter(ArrayList<String> myDataset) {
        mDataset = myDataset;
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder  onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                       int viewType) {
        if (viewType == TYPE_IMAGE) {
            // create a new view
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
            // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
            ImageViewHolder vh = new ImageViewHolder(v);
            return vh;
        } else {
            // create a new view
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.childlayout, parent, false);
            // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
            TextViewHolder vh = new TextViewHolder(v);
            return vh;
        }
    }

    private static final int TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
    private static final int TYPE_GROUP = 2;

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        // here your custom logic to choose the view type
        return position == 0 ? TYPE_IMAGE : TYPE_GROUP;
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder TextViewHolder, int position) {

        switch (TextViewHolder.getItemViewType()) {

            case TYPE_IMAGE:
                ImageViewHolder imageViewHolder = (ImageViewHolder) TextViewHolder;
                // imageViewHolder.mImage.setImageResource(...);
                final String namev = mDataset.get(position);
                imageViewHolder.txtHeader.setText(mDataset.get(position));
                imageViewHolder.txtHeader.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        remove(namev);
                    }
                });

                break;

            case TYPE_GROUP:
                TextViewHolder viewHolder = (TextViewHolder) TextViewHolder;
                //  viewHolder.txtHeader.setText(...)
                final String name = mDataset.get(position);
                viewHolder.textheader.setText(mDataset.get(position));
                viewHolder.textheader.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        remove(name);
                    }
                });

                viewHolder.txtFooter.setText("Footer: " + mDataset.get(position));

                break;
        }
/*
        // - get element from your dataset at this position
        // - replace the contents of the view with that element
        final String name = mDataset.get(position);
        holder.txtHeader.setText(mDataset.get(position));
        holder.txtHeader.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                remove(name);
            }
        });

        holder.txtFooter.setText("Footer: " + mDataset.get(position));
*/
    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible, you can decide your view in `getItemViewType()` of adapter.

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (check condition here with your listData)) // if it is headerView return header type
        return TYPE_HEADER;

    return TYPE_ITEM;
}
```

Now you can get this value in `onCreateViewHolder()`, decide your view for header and child items.

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    if (viewType == TYPE_ITEM) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false);
        return new VHItem(v);
    } else if (viewType == TYPE_HEADER) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.header, parent, false);
        return new VHHeader(v);
    }

}
```

and in your `onBindViewHolder()` show approprite data for header and child view

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (holder instanceof VHItem) {
        String dataItem = getItem(position);
        //cast holder to VHItem and set data
        ((VHItem) holder).description.setText(dataItem);
    } else if (holder instanceof VHHeader) {
        //cast holder to VHHeader and set data for header.
    }
}
```

Reference taken from [here](http://androidgig.com/addheaderview-in-recyclerview/)

Comment: I have added my full code it seems I have set muliple view `onBindViewHolder` and `onCreateViewHolder` as you mentioned but , can you give me an example for getItemViewType ? in your example link they didnt explain much. and I noticed in oncrete view holder you have set different layout `R.layout.header` and R.layout.row_layout can you explain why

Comment: actualy that exaple is just for 1st view so they have taken `0` as default position, in your case `getItemView()` will be used to decide whether view is header or child.

Comment: for header and child i have set different views, `R.layout.header` is for header view and `R.layout.row_layout` is for child view

Comment: okay so I have to create another layout for the child view right ?... as for `getItemView()` is it possible you show me an example how to handle different positions ?

Comment: in if condition of `getItemViewType()` , you can decide whether you want current view as child or header

Comment: ok please check my update code in the question and tell me if i did correct .. but I have a question how to make the layout child below layout parent

Answer (score 0):

First of all I don't think having multiple `RecyclerViews` on one `Activity` is a great idea (it is possible, but has its own problems).

Example you have provided might perfectly use just one `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager`, different ItemTypes and different [spanning](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.html#setSpanSizeLookup(android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup)) for rows. You can implement this all your self (in the end its not that hard) or search for custom implementation of such view (GitHub has lots of them).